# can't find usb mounted to system with ubuntu 16 32 bit

Tags: boot, usb, mount

with lsblk cmd , following info is shown
[image: showing blocked usb as sdb1]

this image is regarding usb info
[image: showing hidden hpfs/ntfs]

can any-body please help me out- how to mount my usb & what's the problem in my system , as i can't see usb mounted even though i mounted usb in usb slot but showing usb details when i see blocked disk with lsblk... as i need to format usb and make it a bootable usb...

Comment: Please no picture from terminal output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Disks app to shows the devices on your system, then use the play arrow to mount the disk you have (if possible).

Or you can reformat the USB from there.